# Splitting text file into smaller files

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, text-files

I am trying to find a way in Python 3 that will take any file that is given as an input, and create 4 smaller files from the original file.  The four smaller files need to be similar length to each other as far as number of characters goes.  If this is not possible to do based on number of characters in a text file, would it be possible to break it up by bytes, but have it still work if the size of the text file changes?

As a test file I was just using the alphabet repeated several time.  This worked exactly as needed.  Where this is being used is in a peer-to-peer file sharing system that has multiple servers.  The file given is supposed to be divided into 4 smaller files, and each file is to be placed on two servers, so that if anything goes wrong there is still a backup.

Comment: The important issue is what character encoding is used in your original text file. If it is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) you should know that a character could be wider than a byte. But your test file don't have such characters (and you should try to add them, e.g. `§` or `Ꮠ` or `δ` or `à` ...)

Comment: See http://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: Is that for a homework, of for a serious application which could be used world-wide? Remember, many people don't use English natively (I am French, also capable of reading Russian). Be at least aware of [Internationalization and Localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) issues. Without improvements (expliciting the encoding you want to use) and motivations (give your work context), your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is doable through character count (in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding a character could take more than a single byte). We can decompose this into two problems:

- First - Count the number of characters in a file.
- Second - Split the file into segments based on the character count.
  A naive solution is below.

I've tested the code below on a simple ASCII file and the UTF-8 example file located here: https://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/UTF-8-demo.html

A small example of your text file would help folks gain some context on your problem.

### Naive Solution

EDIT: Added logic to handle case where the character count was not divisible by the split/segment count.

```
import os

def split_file(in_file_name, split_count):
    """Splits the input file into a specified number of segments."""
    with open(in_file_name, 'r') as in_file:
        # Get a count of characters in the file.
        character_count = 0
        for line in in_file:  
            for character in line: 
                character_count = character_count + 1
        size_per_out_file = character_count / split_count

        # Split up the input file into chunks/segments.
        in_file.seek(0)
        for i in range(0, split_count):
            if (i == (split_count - 1)):
                current_out_content = in_file.read(size_per_out_file + split_count)
            else:
                current_out_content = in_file.read(size_per_out_file)
            out_file_name = '%s_segment_%d.txt' % (in_file_name, i)
            with open(out_file_name, 'w') as current_out_file:
                current_out_file.write(current_out_content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    split_file("in_file.txt", 4)
```

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I just tested it on a UTF-8 file containing a large variety of characters and it worked fine. Why does this fail in your eyes?

Comment: Wrong understanding of Python IO. But then you don't split it in *bytes* but in Unicode characters, and that should be mentioned in your answer. OP asks (naively) to split a file in chunks of same *byte* length ("to break it up by *bytes*"), and for UTF-8 encoded textual files, that would be wrong. Buit your answer is correct, since it does not split a file by bytes but by characters (which with UTF-8 are different).

Comment: I do mention it, at the top of the answer. "First - Count the **number of characters** in a file." and "Second - Split the file into segments based on the **character count** ...".

Comment: But I think OP don't understand that for UTF-8 a character is not the same as a byte, and the OP's question mentions *bytes*. So you are answering correctly to a slightly different question. Hence my small edit to your answer

Comment: As a test file I was just using the alphabet repeated several time.  This worked exactly as needed.  Where this is being used is in a peer-to-peer file sharing system that has multiple servers.  The file given is supposed to be divided into 4 smaller files, and each file is to be placed on two servers, so that if anything goes wrong there is still a backup.

Comment: @Thisguy194: your test file is incomplete. Add some weird UTF-8 characters in it.

Comment: The UTF-8 character did not show up, you are correct But in its place was '\xc5\x98', which corresponds to the symbol that was put there.

Comment: Are you really sure? My guess is that you have split a Unicode character in the middle of its byte sequence, and the result is *not* conforming to UTF-8

Comment: @Thisguy194 If that is the case, your file is probably not UTF-8. You will need to specify the encoding through a parameter in `open(file_name, encoding="your_encoding_here")`.

Answer (score 1):

A textual file is (in 2018) usually [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded. Be aware that many people don't speak or write English natively and could use some other human language and "characters" (including [smileys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smiley)). Read [utf8everywhere.org](http://utf8everywhere.org/) for more. And if it is not UTF-8 encoded you need to understand (by some other way) or decide what exact [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is used.

**In UTF-8 many [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters** (such as `§`, or `é`, or `Ж` or `λ` or `㜼` or `א` or `ح`, `∈`,  etc...) **need *several* bytes to be encoded**. So you cannot split a UTF-8 encoded textual file at some *arbitrary byte boundary*, you should split it at the end of an unicode character.

> As a test file I was just using the alphabet repeated several times

That is naive. You should **test your solution with a file containing also weird characters** (e.g. Greek, Arabic, Cyrillic, Kanji, or math like `∀` or smileys ...), not only English letters.

> would it be possible to break it up by bytes

No, if it is UTF-8 encoded (because as I explained some Unicode characters of the original file could take several bytes). If you split a unicode character taking several bytes "in the middle", the result is generally not UTF-8 compliant (e.g. `é` is UTF-8 encoded by two bytes *`0xc3`* *`0xa9`* in hexadecimal, but *`0xc3`* does *not* encode a *valid* UTF-8 character in isolation)

> but have it still work if the size of the text file changes?

If the original source file changes, you'll need to process it again to split it again in smaller chunks. How to detect when the original source file has changed is a different question (on Linux, in some cases, you might use [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities to detect such changes). Many [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) and [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) keep the modification time (e.g. the [`st_mtime`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)) given by [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) on POSIX systems) and you could use it to trigger the split. Of course **the details are *operating system* specific**.

You might want to split your textual file in chunks of entire *lines* (so not at arbitrary byte boundaries). You could use [split(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html) on Linux for that (and you could use [wc(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html) with `-l` to count the lines on Linux).

Of course, you could easily code in Python a function counting the number of lines in a textual file, and another function splitting it in chunks of entire lines, since Python has facilities (e.g. the `readline` function of [io](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html)) to read a whole line. Or you can, as [answered by Brennen Sprimont](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53800472/841108), split your file into chunks of approximately equal character length, which is *not* a byte length (as your question explicitly asks: "to break it up by bytes").